# If Sobolev space is isometric to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ then Sobolev space is complete?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, complete-spaces

[image]

[image]

My attempt:

Let $H^2(\mathbb{R})=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \left\|u\right\|_{H^2(\mathbb{R})}:=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{u})\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}<\infty\right\}$
the Sobolev space

Let $T:H^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $Tu=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{u})$ linear operator.

\begin{align}
d_2(Tu,Tv)&=\left\|Tu-Tv\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\\
&=\left\|T(u-v)\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\\
&=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{(u-v)})\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}\\
&=\left\|u-v\right\|_{\mathcal{H}^2(\mathbb{R})}\\
&=d_1(u,v)
\end{align}

Therefore $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete? (because $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete)

Thanks.

Problem: Let $X$
be a complete normed space and assume the normed space $Y$
is isometric to Show that $Y$ is complete ([Isometry of a complete normed space is also complete.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085721/isometry-of-a-complete-normed-space-is-also-complete))

Actualization: In my case, $T^{-1}:L^2(\mathbb{R})\to H^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $T^{-1}f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}\widehat{u}(\xi))$ satisfies $\left\|T^{-1}u\right\|_{H^2(\mathbb{R})}=\left\|u\right\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$. Then $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete?
$

Comment: but this is an "if and only if" but, I need only the "if" or not?